# How to remove gray section bar in Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I use [Eureka library](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) and with this code:

```
class MainViewController: FormViewController {

  var firstName = ""

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Форма заполнения"
    form +++=

        Section()

        <<< TextRow() { row in
            row.title = "Имя"
            row.placeholder = "Введите свое имя"
        }.onChange { [weak self] row in
            self?.firstName = row.value!
        }
  }
}
```

i got the following picture:

[image]

And i want to remove the gray bar between navigation panel and row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you mean is to use Plain Style TableView add this to your code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        if tableView == nil {
            tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
            tableView?.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth.union(.FlexibleHeight)
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // my code ...
}
```

Taken from https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/218

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
form +++ Section() {            
        var header = HeaderFooterView<UIView>(.class)            
        header.height = { 0.1 } // `height` > 0
        $0.header = header
    }
<<< ...
```

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 3

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if tableView == nil {
        tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        tableView?.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth.union(.flexibleHeight)
    }
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to remove that tiny image between navbar and bodyview

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the result.